# Obtener el campo con el valor mas alto agrupados por códigos

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas por `materiaprimaID`, las tablas son las siguientes:

```
**Raw_matrial**
materiaprimaID (int)
codigo (int)

**composicion**
compuesto (varchat)
entryNumber (int)
porcentaje (int)
materiaprimaID (int)
```

Intento crear un consulta en sql para obtener de todos los códigos el campo con el valor más alto de porcentaje.

Un código contiene varios compuesto con su porcentaje

```
Código | Porcentaje  | Compuesto
6014   | 0,084       | Crotonaldehyde
6014   | 0,022       | Hexanal, n
6014   | 98,810      | Furfural
6014   | 0,012       | Benzofuran
6021   | 99,595      | Iso Propyl Cinnamate
6021   | 0,305       | Ethyl Cinnamate
```

Y quiero obtener todos los código pero solo me interesa el compuesto con el porcentaje más alto, esperando obtener:

```
Código | Porcentaje  | Compuesto
6014   | 98,810      | Furfural
6021   | 99,595      | Iso Propyl Cinnamate
```

Tengo un query, que se asemeja pero no me da los resultados esperados:

```
SELECT
raw_material.codigo,
composicion.porcentaje,
composicion.compuesto
FROM
composicion
INNER JOIN raw_material ON raw_material.materiaprimaID = composicion.materiaprimaID
ORDER BY
composicion.porcentaje DESC
```

RESULTADO:

```
6021    99,595  Iso Propyl Cinnamate
6014    98,810  Furfural
6014    0,609   Methyl Furfural, 5-
6021    0,305   Ethyl Cinnamate
6014    0,141   Acetyl Furan, 2-
6014    0,084   Crotonaldehyde
6014    0,057   Guaiacol
6014    0,022   Hexanal, n
```

Pero yo solo quiero el Compuesto de cada código con el porcentaje más alto.
Y **no puedo hacer un LIMIT** porque el la búsqueda puede haber centenares de códigos.

Agradezco su respuesta.

Gracias.

Comment: Has intentado usando Group BY ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando conseguir es algo así:

```
SELECT codigo,porcentage,compuesto FROM (
    SELECT materiaprimaID,
      MAX(porcentage) porcentage
      FROM composicion
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID,porcentage)
  JOIN raw_matrial USING(materiaprimaID);
```

Para este dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_matrial(
  materiaprimaID int PRIMARY KEY,
  codigo int
  );
CREATE TABLE composicion(
  compuesto varchar(31),
  entryNumber int,
  porcentage float,
  materiaprimaID int,
  FOREIGN KEY(materiaprimaID) REFERENCES raw_matrial(materiaprimaID)
  );
INSERT INTO raw_matrial (materiaprimaID, codigo) VALUES
  (14,6014),(21,6021);
INSERT INTO composicion (materiaprimaID, porcentage, compuesto) VALUES
  (14,0.084,'Crotonaldehyde'),  
  (14,0.022,'Hexanal, n'),  
  (14,98.810,'Furfural'),   
  (14,0.012,'Benzofuran'),  
  (21,99.595,'Iso Propyl Cinnamate'),   
  (21,0.305,'Ethyl Cinnamate');
```

El resultado sería:

> ```
> 6014  98,81   Furfural
> 6021  99,595  Iso Propyl Cinn
> ```

De cada grupo, el que más porcentaje tiene.

La explico un poco: primero buscas los máximos de cada Código (que tiene varios compuestos) y después buscas los compuestos a los que corresponden combinando la subconsulta y la tabla por dos campos. No se puede hacer directamente en `MAX` porque el SQL no funciona así.

El `GROUP BY 1` es para agrupar por el primer campo que aparezca tras el `SELECT`, es una forma abreviada de escribir `GROUP BY Código`

El alias `c1`, o cualquier otro, es obligatorio utilizarlo cuando haces uso de subconsultas. Es una combinación de una tabla y una subconsulta. Anidar quizá me suena más a bucles...

Comment: Correcto, acabo de añadir un par de explicaciones. Cualquier cosa más, me decís, por favor.

Comment: hola, Muchas gracias es exactamente el resultado que busco pero no entiendo lo de c1. Y luego realmente son dos tablas anidadas por materiaprimaID

**raw_material**
materiaprimaID
codigo (int)
Y mas campos

**composicion**
compuesto
porcentaje
materiaprimaID

¿en tu ejemplo como integro las dos tablas?

Gracias.

Comment: En tu comentario aparecen campos que no aparecen en la pregunta. Te sugiero hacer una nueva pregunta con las cuestiones adicionales que te han ido surgiendo

Comment: he editado la pregunta inicial añadiendo la información de la tablas. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, ya te entiendo... :) vale, vale, ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Eres mi ídolo, un genio, funciona a la perfección. muchas gracias :)

Comment: Gracias a ti. Y que has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

- Usa la función **`MAX`** y pasale como argumento el nombre de la columna donde deseas obtener el valor máximo
- Agrupa por el resto de columnas que tienes en el **`select`** menos la que resultó de usar la función de agregación arriba mencionada
- Ordena de forma descendente por la columna calculada a la cual idealmente dale un alias
- Para solo quedar con 2 registros has un **`limit 2`**

**Consulta**

```
SELECT
raw_material.codigo,
MAX(composicion.porcentaje) AS Maximo,
composicion.compuesto
FROM
composicion
INNER JOIN raw_material ON raw_material.materiaprimaID = composicion.materiaprimaID
GROUP BY raw_material.codigo, composicion.compuesto
ORDER BY Maximo DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Y la salida debería ser así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero como he dicho no puedo hacer un LIMIT ya que esto es un ejemplo pero en realidad hay cientos de códigos y si pongo un LIMIT solo me mostraría los dos primeros. 
He probado tu sugerencia quitandole el LIMIT y este es el resultado:
Pero me muestra todos los compuestos

Comment: mmm soy novato en esto, agradecería un ejemplo. de como quedaría con el concat.

Comment: Creo que ya entiendo a qué te refieres y el `CONCAT` no te lo resolverá :(, necesitarás una subconsulta, porque el agrupamiento es por código

Comment: ¿alguna idea para la sub-consulta? gracias

Comment: Ya que no dispongo de un PC para construir un ejemplo y editar la respuesta, entonces esperemos el aporte de @DavidJP