# búsqueda se similitud dentro secuencia msql

Tags: mysql, sql, busqueda

Nuestro amigo David JP me ayudo ayer en un problema en una secuencia sql (aquí el link: [Obtener el campo con el valor mas alto agrupados por códigos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/349394/obtener-el-campo-con-el-valor-mas-alto-agrupados-por-c%c3%b3digos)) pero luego al solucionar el problema luego me ha surgido otro inconveniente.

Tengo dos tablas de materia prima relacionadas entre ellas por materiaprimaID, las tablas son las siguientes:

```
**Raw_matrial**
materiaprimaID (int)
codigo (int)

**composicion**
compuesto (varchat)
entryNumber (int)
porcentaje (int)
materiaprimaID (int)
totalcompuestos (int)
```

cada materia prima contiene: código, nombre, una composición (compuesto y porcentaje) y cada compuesto tiene un numero identificador (entryNumber)

Por ejemplo

```
Codigo | Nombre         | Compuesto        | entryNumber | porcentaje | totalcompuestos | materiaprimaID
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Crotonaldehyde   | 986         | 0,084      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Hexanal, n       | 117         | 0,022      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Acetic Acid      | 109         | 0,014      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Furfural         | 993         | 98,810     |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Benzofuran       | 3291        | 0,012      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Acetyl Furan, 2- | 1014        | 0,141      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Methyl Furfural  | 1016        | 0,609      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| 2 Acetyl 5 Methyl| 2261        | 0,010      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Guaiacol         | 122         | 0,057      |10               |1
6014   |FURFURAL NATURAL| Ethyl Guaicol, 4-| 802         | 0,015      |10               |1
6021   |Propyl Cinnamate| Propyl Cinnamate | 407         | 99,595     |2                |2
6021   |Propyl Cinnamate| Guaiacol         | 122         | 0,305      |2                |2
```

Esto es la base de datos de las materias primas.
ahora lo que quiero es relacionar una composición incógnita "llamada MATCH" y tengo que averiguar que materias primas componen dicho MATCH

tengo una tabla (que para resumir solo pondré los campos útiles para la explicación) para los MATCH que es la siguiente:

```
**composiciónMatch**
compuesto (varchat)
entryNumberMatch (int)
porcentaje (int)
```

Ejemplo: composición del MATCH

```
Compuesto        | entryNumberMatch | porcentaje 
Crotonaldehyde   |  986             | 4,384
Hexanal, n       |  117             | 0,001 
Acetic Acid      |  109             | 0,031
Furfural         |  993             | 96,031    
Benzofuran       |  3291            | 0,484 
Acetyl Furan, 2- |  1014            | 0,707 
Methyl Furfural, |  1016            | 0,036
2 Acetyl 5 Methyl|  2261            | 0,017
Guaiacol         |  122             | 0,826
Ethyl Guaicol,   |  802             | 0,021
Propyl Cinnamate |  407             | 4,000
```

Por ejemplo yo quiero buscar Propyl Cinnamate y Guaiacol la concordancia con los códigos 6014 y 6021
es la siguiente:

```
      | concordancia  = (Nº compuestos buscados coincidentes con la materia prima / total compuestos *100) 
6014  | 10%  (de los dos compuestos buscados solamente 1 compuesto está en el código 6014 de 10 compuestos totales)         
6021  | 100% (de los dos compuestos buscados los dos están en el código 6021)
```

si ahora busco por ejemplo solamente el Propyl Cinnamate la concordancia es

```
      | concordancia 
6014  | 0%  (el compuesto Propyl Cinnamate no está en el código 6014)         
6021  | 50% (el compuestos Propyl Cinnamate se encuentra en el código 6021 de un total de 2 compuestos)
```

esto los tenia solucionado con esta secuencia SQL

```
SELECT
raw_material.producto,
raw_material.codigo,
ROUND((Count(composicion.materiaprimaID) /composicion.totalcompuestos)*100,2) AS concordance, 
composicion.compuesto,
composicion.porcentaje
FROM raw_material
INNER JOIN composicion ON raw_material.materiaprimaID = composicion.materiaprimaID
WHERE composicion.entryNumber = 407 OR composicion.entryNumber = 122
GROUP BY raw_material.codigo
ORDER BY concordance DESC
```

Resultado

```
**producto       | código  | concordancia | compuesto       | porcentaje**
Propyl Cinnamate |  6021   |    100,00    | Propyl Cinnamate| 99,595
FURFURAL NATURAL |  6014   |    10,00     | Guaiacol        | 0,057
```

Pero además de esto de la concordancia necesitaba otra sub-consulta explicada en el link mencionada arriba. Que me soluciono muy amablemente David JP pero a la hora de implementarlo la concordancia no funciona.

La consulta que tengo ahora es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
producto,
codigo, 
ROUND((Count(composicion.materiaprimaID) /composicion.totalcompuestos)*100,2) AS concordance, 
compositionID, 
compuesto,
porcentaje
FROM
(SELECT materiaprimaID, MAX(porcentaje) porcentaje FROM composicion GROUP BY 1)  C1
JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID,porcentaje) JOIN raw_material USING(materiaprimaID)
WHERE raw_material.producto in (composicion.entryNumber = 407 AND composicion.entryNumber = 122 AND composicion.entryNumber = 109) 
GROUP BY raw_material.codigo
```

Resultado (buscando tres compuestos):

```
**producto       | código | concordancia | compuesto       | porcentaje**
 Propyl Cinnamate | 6021   |    50,00     | Propyl Cinnamate| 99,595
 FURFURAL NATURAL | 6014   |    10,00     | furfural        | 98,810
```

El resultado que deseo si hago una búsqueda de Propyl Cinnamate y Guaiacol y acido acetico (siguiendo el ejemplo de arriba) es la siguiente:

```
**producto       | código  | concordancia | compuesto       | porcentaje**
Propyl Cinnamate |  6021   |    100,00    | Propyl Cinnamate| 99,595
FURFURAL NATURAL |  6014   |    20,00     | furfural        | 98.81
```

Ordenado por concordancia decreciente.

Se que es un poco lioso y más de explicar si se requiere más explicación para entender decidmelo

Agradezco su respuesta.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @RaúlGomez, ¿podrías añadir el dataset en formato mysql para tratar de replicar tu base de datos con esos registros de ejemplo?

Comment: No consigo aclararme entre compuestos, códigos, entries, productos, concordancias, porcentajes y matches. Definitivamente. el dataset con todos los vínculos entre tablas y alguna definición o ejemplo sencillo, ayudaría bastante a entender el problema. ¿Sería posible?

Comment: un ejemplo gráfico puede que ayude a entender.
www.matchmaking.gq   user: rufo; pass 123

al entrar lo primero que ves es la materias primas que hay, si clicas veras toda su información (codigo, composición, ect)

Comment: Como aún no lo entiendo no te puedo decir, pero la estructura del modelo de datos resulta a veces más útil que las explicaciones. El resultado que esperas, que ya has aportado, también ayuda mucho. Tal vez nombres más sencillos... Pero vamos poco a poco. Lo primero: el dataset

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia pero como exporto el dataset?

Comment: ¿Te sirve si te paso el archivo *.sql? Con todas las tablas y sus datos

Comment: Exacto, así se pueden exportar datos... En phpMyAdmin Exportar, y dejas unos registros de ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por dejar la pregunta cerrada, dejo la conclusión a la que hemos finalmente hemos llegado: para combinar dos subconsultas debes seguir una estructura como ésta:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    ...
  ) c1 JOIN (
    ...
  ) c2 USING(codigo)
  ORDER BY concordance DESC;
```

En `c1` introduces tu consulta y en `c2` la mía, obteniendo algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    raw_material.producto,
    raw_material.codigo,
    ROUND((Count(composicion.materiaprimaID)
      /composicion.totalcompuestos)*100,2) AS concordance
    FROM raw_material
    INNER JOIN composicion 
      ON raw_material.materiaprimaID = composicion.materiaprimaID
    WHERE composicion.entryNumber = 407 
      OR composicion.entryNumber = 122
      OR composicion.entryNumber = 109
    GROUP BY raw_material.codigo  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT codigo,porcentaje,compuesto FROM (
        SELECT materiaprimaID,
          MAX(porcentaje) porcentaje
          FROM composicion
          GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1 JOIN composicion USING(materiaprimaID,porcentaje)
      JOIN raw_material USING(materiaprimaID)  
  ) c2 USING(codigo)
  ORDER BY concordance DESC;
```

Con este resultado:

> ```
> 1 6021    IsoPropyl Cinnamate 100,00  99,595  Iso Propyl Cinnamate
> 2 6014    FURFURAL NATURAL    20,00   98,810  Furfural
> ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona a la perfección